# NHibernate, the Parallel Framework, and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

hey guys, we have a loop that:

1.Loops over several thousand xml files. Altogether we're parsing millions of "user" nodes.

2.In each iteration we parse a "user" xml, do custom deserialization

3.finally, in each iteration, we send our object to nhibernate for saving. We use:

```
.SaveOrUpdateAndFlush(user);
```

This is a lengthy process, and we thought it would be a perfect candidate for testing out the .NET 4.0 Parallel libraries. So we wrapped the loop in a:

```
Parallel.ForEach();
```

After doing this, we start getting "random" Timeout Exceptions from SQL Server, and finally, after leaving it running all night, OutOfMemory unhandled exceptions.

I haven't done deep debugging on this yet, but what do you guys think. Is this simply a limitation of SQL Server, or could it be our NHibernate setup, or what?

cheers

andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` is not magic. You still have to manage the units of work, connection pools, etc, with the added complexity of multiple threads. Also, remember that the NHibernate Session is **not** thread-safe (each thread should have its own session)

Your timeout exceptions could be caused by deadlocks or exhaustion of the connection pool (you didn't post the stack trace or the inner exceptions, so it's a guess)

OutOfMemory exceptions are probably due to memory leaks; you are probably leaving your sessions and entities hanging around. You should use a profiler like [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) to find the cause (both have free trials)

Comment: thanks diego. Yeah, I realize it's not magic ;), though it seems like it! it certainly helped with the XML processing. Anyways, as for NHibernate Sessions not being threadsafe... I thought the parallel framework DID handle that, am I mistaken? You mention "deadlocks". Could the bad handling of Nhibernate sessions cause this? And how would I got about addressing "exhaustion of the connection pool"? cool, much appreciated

Comment: That's a lot of questions :-D   1. How can the parallel session "handle" something it's not aware of? 2. Deadlocks are caused by DB access, but again, it's hard to tell without more information. 3. You must make sure sessions and transactions are being closed properly.

Comment: :-D yeah, sorry diego. You've really helped me out, cheers. I'll start digging around a abit more